Backing of Treasury Zeros/STRIPS
Treasuries are issued by the United States government. However, from what I understand all treasury zero coupon bonds are issued by financial institutions. This may be wrong, but I would imagine a bank would buy a bunch of bonds, split the coupon payments and the principal to sell individually, while holding on the original bonds.
I know this is probably impossible, but what happens if the issuing institution goes bankrupt? Could the bonds default? Are there any rules and regulations to ensure treasury zeros are always backed?

all treasury zero coupon bonds are issued by financial institutions - source please?

@littleadv I guess I stand corrected. What about outside of T-bills?

I believe you are thinking of Treasury STRIPS which are Treasury bonds that are repackaged by financial institutions that keep the coupons and sell the rest of the bond at a discount.
(Not all zero-coupon treasury notes are STRIPS, though - the Treasury also sell notes at a discount rather than paying a coupon)
They are still backed by the Treasury and have virtually no default risk, even if the financial institution that packages them goes bankrupt (it is not the bank that is paying the principal at maturity, but the government).

Thanks for answering, that clears things up a little. I guess what I'm trying to ask is how does the process of creating treasury STRIPS actually work? If an institution packages them, somebody has to hold on to the underlying bond in the mean time. What happens if something happens to the underlying bond through mismanagement by the institution? I might be misunderstanding something

I also didn't realize the treasury sold zero coupon notes. I know there are shorter term bills, but how can I identify if a long term zero is directly issued by the treasury? On e-trade most zeros are labelled STRIPS, but I found one that didn't have that in the name. I searched the CUSIP and found a document about an offering that seemed to say that if the bond were made into STRIPS then the CUSIP would be that.

I can't speak to the specific details of what would happen in the event of the institution's bankruptcy, but rest assured that STRIPS are indeed safe from default risk. My guess is that any STRIPS they hold would be transferred to another institution as part of the bankruptcy proceedings. The bottom line is that the bonds are still backed by the govt. You have no counterparty risk.
